# mysql query for getting max count of row's data by date?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

i have one table name as a_ad_display with following column

```
displayId | campaignId | displaytime(date)

1          |    2      | 2012-12-19 12:41:08
2          |    2      | 2012-12-19 01:41:08
3          |    1      | 2012-12-20 10:41:08
4          |    1      | 2012-12-20 02:41:08
5          |    1      | 2012-12-21 12:41:08
6          |    2      | 2012-12-21 01:41:08
7          |    1      | 2012-12-21 12:41:08
8          |    1      | 2012-12-21 02:41:08
```

there is a multiple entry with same campaignId should be there.now what i want is to first of all fetch the campaignId with the highest count in a_ad_display and for that campaignId i want to get total number of count within the date

eg..from above table i have 1 number campaignId with highest row count

so for 1 number campaignId i want to display records like this..

```
        **Date**     | **countPerDay**
 2012-12-19          |      0
 2012-12-20          |      2
 2012-12-21          |      3
```

how can i achieve this in mysql database...hope anyone can guide me...

Comment: why you want to display date as 2012-12-20 01:41:08 dont you think its giving wrong countperday since there is only on 1 record at 01:41:08?

Comment: yes...sorry..but i just want it to be like 2012-12-19 .please see my updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query

```
select 
    count(campaignId) as TCount,
    DATE(displayTime) as `Date`
from a_ad_display
where campaignId = 1
group by DATE(displayTime)
```

Although it will not display 0.

EDIT :

OK This is modified and fetches your result.

```
select
  date(a.displayTime) as `DisplayTime`,
  ifnull(l.TCount,0) as TCount
from a_ad_display as a
  left join (select
           count(campaignId) as TCount,
           displayTime
         from a_ad_display
         where campaignId = 1
         group by DATE(displayTime)) as l
    on date(a.displayTime) = date(l.displayTime)
group by DATE(a.displayTime)
```

### Demo

MORE EDITS :

```
select
  date(a.displayTime) as `DisplayTime`,
  ifnull(l.TCount,0) as TCount
from a_ad_display as a
  left join (select
           count(campaignId) as TCount,
           displayTime
         from a_ad_display
         where campaignId = 1
         group by DATE(displayTime)) as l
    on date(a.displayTime) = date(l.displayTime)
group by DATE(a.displayTime)
order by a.displaytime desc limit 5
```

This is how you can select latest 5 records. If you want to select the latest campaign you can use a subquery instead of 1 take a look at this query

```
select
  date(a.displayTime) as `DisplayTime`,
  ifnull(l.TCount,0) as TCount
from a_ad_display as a
  left join (select
       count(campaignId) as TCount,
       displayTime
     from a_ad_display
     where campaignId = (select  campaignId from a_ad_display group by campaignId order by count(campaignId) desc limit 1)
     group by DATE(displayTime)) as l
    on date(a.displayTime) = date(l.displayTime)
group by DATE(a.displayTime)
```

EDITS :

I have edited the query this will fetch higher occurance campaignId and fetch results accordingly

### Demo

Comment: select campaignId from a_ad_display group by campaignId LIMIT 0,1       This query will select the campaignId with the highest row count which i want to use in where clause and also what should i change if i want to get last 5 or 10 days record only

Comment: @BhavikKama how come your query will select the highest row count?

Comment: will it not??actully i tried in mysql with this (select campaignId from a_ad_display group by campaignId LIMIT 0,1) and its giving me the campaignId which have highest count..i am just beginner so if m wrong pelase correct me

Comment: you can add order by a.displaytime desc limit 5 to get 5 records

Comment: and what about the where clause (WHERE CampaignId=1) i want to get this campaign id with highest occuring campaignId in a_ad_display table's row

Comment: @BhavikKama i have edited the answer. for latest row always use MAX.

Comment: hey raheel...it selects the highest value of campaignId..not with highest occurence

Comment: What do you mean by highest occurance? can you explain what you need?

Comment: i mean to say if there is two campaignId's(1,2) entries in a_ad_display and if there is more rows with the campaignId 1 then campaign Id 2..then it should be 1 whoes occurence is more

Comment: @BhavikKama see the last query of my Edit and demo for checking

Comment: Welcome! No problem sorry for late reply i was busy

Comment: i haev one more query to ask.if u have time then can u pls join me in chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24435/discussion-between-bhavik-kama-and-raheel-shan)

Comment: OK @BhavikKama i am available

Answer (score 2):

this will show 0 also

```
 select 
       sum(case when campaignId = @inputCompainid then 1 else 0 end) as TCount, 
        DATE(displayTime) as `Date`
    from a_ad_display
    group by DATE(displayTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following query gives u list of records for each campaignId

```
select campaignId,date(displaytime) as Date,count(*) as countPerDay from a_ad_display group by campaignId,date(displaytime);
```

if you need for specfic campaignId, use this :

```
select campaignId,date(displaytime) as Date,count(*) as countPerDay from a_ad_display group by campaignId,date(displaytime) having campaignId=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

sory for asking this, but which one of this query is better??

1.the answer by Mr.[raheel shan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713141/raheel-shan)

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DATE(a.displayTime) AS `DisplayTime`,IFNULL(l.TCount,0) AS TCount
FROM a_ad_display AS a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
       COUNT(campaignId) AS TCount,
       displayTime
     FROM a_ad_display
     WHERE campaignId = 1
     GROUP BY DATE(displayTime)) AS l
ON DATE(a.displayTime) = DATE(l.displayTime)
GROUP BY DATE(a.displayTime);


id  select_type  table         type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra                                            
1   PRIMARY      <derived2>    ALL                                     2                                                   
1   PRIMARY      a             ALL                                     8     Using temporary; Using filesort               
2   DERIVED      a_ad_display  ALL                                     8     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

2.or using this one

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DATE(a_ad_display.`displaytime`) AS `DATE`, 
               COUNT(a.`campaignId`) AS `COUNT Per Day` 
        FROM a_ad_display 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT `a_ad_display`.`displayId`,
                          `a_ad_display`.`campaignId` 
                   FROM `a_ad_display` 
                   WHERE `a_ad_display`.`campaignId`=1) a 
        ON (`a_ad_display`.`displayId`=a.`displayId`)
        GROUP BY `a_ad_display`.`displaytime`;

id  select_type  table         type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra                              
1   PRIMARY      a_ad_display  ALL                                     8     Using temporary; Using filesort  
1   PRIMARY      <derived2>    ALL                                     5                                       
2   DERIVED      a_ad_display  ALL                                     8     Using where
```

thanks before & after :D

**EDIT** for highest campaignId occurance

```
SELECT DATE(a_ad_display.`displaytime`) AS `DATE`, COUNT(a.`campaignId`) AS `COUNT Per Day` FROM a_ad_display 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `a_ad_display`.`displayId`,`a_ad_display`.`campaignId` FROM `a_ad_display`
   INNER  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(`a_ad_display`.`campaignId`) AS `count`, `a_ad_display`.`campaignId` 
        FROM `a_ad_display` 
        GROUP BY `a_ad_display`.`campaignId` 
        ORDER BY `count` DESC 
        LIMIT 1) b ON (a_ad_display.`campaignId`=b.`campaignId`)
   ) a ON (`a_ad_display`.`displayId`=a.`displayId`)
GROUP BY `DATE`;
```

GROUP BY `a_ad_display`.`displaytime`; **/* wrong in this statement ..., sorry*/**
it should be working now ..... try again.
You can check in here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc75b/1, hope it's workin :D

Comment: before i answer this can u please help me bit for using this line -> WHERE `a_ad_display`.`campaignId`=1) a ....i want to use the campaignId which have highest occurence of rows in a_ad_display table

Comment: there you go for highest campaignId occurance, now how about my first question, cause reading EXPLAIN results still confused me :-(

Comment: can u please see my question again...???at last...i want to change the condition of Where CampaignId=1 to campaignId=(which most occures in row of table a_ad_display table)

Comment: now leave it..i got my problem solved by Raheel..thanx for your help..and i would say that the one suggested by Raheel is more better

Comment: actually I need a reason why it's better, but thats ok, by the way I've re-edit my answer, and thank you